# How to get current iis website name in ConfigureService() method in startup class in AspCore 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asihttprequest, httpcontext

I need to get current iis website (started website) name in configureservice method in statup class in aspcore2.
I need it in sub class of configureservice
I try HttpContextAccessor but it always is null

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code in the startup class:

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        var name = Configuration["ASPNETCORE_APPL_PATH"];
    }
```

[IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez3b2.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG8jX.png)

Comment: He could write it Configuration["ASPNETCORE_APPL_PATH"]

Comment: If you dig further into ASP.NET Core module source code, this value is the application virtual path, not exactly the "IIS website name". But it is the closest.